# Get an integer with a certain prefix [Java]

Tags: java, regex

Given strings like `Engine Name 470/485HP and some other text here about 100RPM or torque` and I want to extract a number right before `HP`. In this example method should return `485`. Numbers are guaranteed to be integers (no `-123.45` to worry about). Pattern `digitsHP` only appears once per string. Cases like `1234-5678HP` are possible and `5678` is an expected result. I came up with a method that splits string by spaces, for each substring it checks if it ends with HP. If it does, method finds the last block of numbers and saves it. What is a better way to do this? I suspect it might be a regex one-liner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String myStr = "Engine Name 470/485HP and some other text here about 100RPM or torque";
    List<Integer> list = parseIntegerWithSuffixIgnoreCase(myStr, "HP");
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
}

public static List<Integer> parseIntegerWithSuffixIgnoreCase(String input, String suffix) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] rawStrings = input.split("\\s");

    for (String rawString : rawStrings) {
        if (rawString.toUpperCase().endsWith(suffix)) {

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(rawString);
            List<String> allNumericMatches = new ArrayList<>();
            while (m.find()) {
                allNumericMatches.add(m.group());
            }
            Integer value = Integer.parseInt(allNumericMatches.get(allNumericMatches.size() - 1));
            result.add(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Use `\\b\\d+(?=HP\\b)` or [`\\b(\\d+)HP\\b`](http://ideone.com/6im4kH).

Comment: Why did you decide to use `split` in the first place? Is it possible that your string will contain data like `foo123hpbar` in which case `123hp` should be ignored?

Comment: Yes, the `split()` seems gratuitous, at best.  Likely it's just going to slow down your searching, at least if the sample input is any indication.

Comment: Speaking of performance, for simple searches like this it's really easy to just search for an "H", followed by a "P", then back up and copy the digits manually.  This can be much much faster than a regex engine if performance does become an issue.  Consider also using `indexOf("HP")` if you need more performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `HP` to your regex...

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+HP)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("asdf 123HP 123");
        if (m.find())
            System.out.println("result - " + m.group(1));
```

Comment: I made it more general by:
`String matcherPattern = "([0-9]+" + suffix + ")";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(matcherPattern);`
 Works great, thank you.

Comment: OP doesn't want the suffix included. In this case "\\D(\\d+)HP" fits the bill.
Or "\\D(\\d+)" + suffix

Comment: There is no point in wrapping entire regex in parenthesis like `(regex)` because entire match is already in group 0, so there is no need to add another group just for that. Maybe you meant to store only numeric part in it? In that case you need to more `)` before `HP` like `([0-9]+)HP`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this method :

```
public static List<Integer> parseIntegerWithSuffixIgnoreCase(String input, String suffix) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.format("(\\d+)%s(?:$|\\W+)", suffix));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        result.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here I have used this regex : `(\d+)SUFFIX(?:$|\W+)`

- `(\d+)` - means zero or more digit and make capture group 1
- `$` means end of string
- `\w+` zero or more non word character
- `(?:)` means not capture this group